# Hide Workflow properties

Tags: workflow, cewp

In Sharepoint 2013 on-premises I am creating a Workflow Interface. Actually I would like to avoid users to see the Workflow process on a List, so they just can see the Status but not click on it and also hide/delete the link on the E-Mail they receive.

I think I saw some Solutions in SharePoint Designer, but actually I am not allowed to use it (Although I am considering to order it).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the workflow status from the list you can edit the list view [Edit Views](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)

To Edit the Email part you required SharePoint Designer which is free and can be downloadable from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35491)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I want the Status, I don´t want it as a link, but as a normal field where they can see if it´s in Progress and so. About the E-Mail I guess SharePoint Designer has the Solution (It would make my work extremely easier) but the Company where I work has thousands of limitations and they are giving me many Problems to get one.